# Archiving all in Gmail inbox--webmail vs IMAP

Tags: gmail, imap, thunderbird, webmail, gmail-imap

I have about 13,000 messages in a Gmail inbox, and would like to switch to a system of archiving messages once they're dealt with, rather than using read/unread status.

I know [how to do this via webmail](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/quick-tip-archive-old-email-in-your-gmail-inbox-the-easy-way/), but then, I usually use Thunderbird for Gmail.  Is there any advantage to performing the operation via webmail or via Thunderbird?  Which will take the least time for Thunderbird to work through in the end to get them sync'd up?

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, I think that the best option is to do the bulk operations in http://mail.google.com just before you could left alone your Thunderbird instance for several hours, as the sync process could take "a while" and consume "a lot" of resources of your computer.

**References**
[How actions sync in IMAP - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/77657?hl=en)
[Deleting IMAP messages - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78755)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if the best option will take "a while", what makes it the best option?  What more details were you referring to that would help answer?

Comment: Details about how do you organize your messages, if you use only Thunderbird to organize them, the average size of the messages, the connection speed and other things like that could help to a Web App Jedi. I'm just an Initiate :).